# SSIS - BIDS Helper Install

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to install BIDS Helper, for use on Visual Studio 2015. The most recent pack, posted in May 2015 on Codeplex, does not appear to be compatible with VS 2015. After downloading it to my Program Files, I get a bunch of DLL files, but no installation files (the prompt said it should have been auto added, during the download). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015 (and above once we support them) you can install BIDS Helper from the Visual Studio Gallery as described [here](https://bideveloperextensions.github.io/features/InstallingfromtheVisualStudioGallery/).